# I'm unsure of how I should be calling my methods to draw my snake with StdDraw

Tags: java, methods, draw

I'm using StdDraw to create a snake program. When I run my program it jumps to the game over display without actually entering the game. I'm sure there are quite a few things I have to fix, but please point me in the right direction

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.util.Random;

public final class Snake {
   
   // Enum for user input & snake movement
   enum Direction { UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT }
   private static Direction direction;
   
   // Declare game constants
   private static int WIDTH = 800;
   private static int HEIGHT = 800;
   private static int UNIT_SIZE = 40;
   private static int GAME_UNITS = (WIDTH * HEIGHT) / UNIT_SIZE;

   // Grid for snake & food coordinates
   private static int[][] grid;          // Game board
   private static int[] snakeX, snakeY;  // Arrays to store snake's body's coordinates
   private static int foodX, foodY;      // Food's coordinates
   
   private static boolean gameOver;
   private static int snakeLength;
   private static int score;
   private static Random random = new Random();
   
   // Main calls game methods
   public static void main (final String[] args) { 
      StdDraw.enableDoubleBuffering();   // Smoother graphics
      launchGame();                      // Launch game

      // Loop to play game with functions
      while (!gameOver) {
         handleInput();                  // Controls
         updateSnake();                  // Move snake
         draw();                         // Draw game elements; snake, food, & score
         StdDraw.show();                 // Show graphics
         StdDraw.pause (100);            // Pause to control game speed
      }
      
      gameOverDisplay();                 // Game over display
   }
   
   // Method initializes elements in game launch
   private static void launchGame () {
      // Create game window
      StdDraw.setCanvasSize (WIDTH, HEIGHT);  // Canvas size
      StdDraw.setXscale (0, WIDTH);           // X-axis scale
      StdDraw.setYscale (0, HEIGHT);          // Y-axis scale

      // Initialize game elements
      direction = Direction.RIGHT;       // Default direction
      gameOver = false;                  // Game over flag
      snakeLength = 3;                   // Snake's initial length
      score = 0;
      
      grid = new int[WIDTH / UNIT_SIZE][HEIGHT / UNIT_SIZE];
      snakeX = new int[GAME_UNITS];      // Store x position of snake's body
      snakeY = new int[GAME_UNITS];             // Store y position of snake's body
      
      // Initialize snake's position
      for (int i = 0; i < snakeLength; i++) {
         // Place snake in the middle of the board
         snakeX[i] = GAME_UNITS / 2 - i;   // Snake's body blocks
         snakeY[i] = GAME_UNITS / 2;  
      }
      
      spawnFood();
   }
   
   // Method handles user input & direction
   private static void handleInput () {
      // Check for arrow key presses
      if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed (KeyEvent.VK_UP) && direction != Direction.DOWN) {
         direction = Direction.UP;
      } else if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed (KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) && direction != Direction.UP) {
         direction = Direction.DOWN;
      } else if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed (KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) && direction != Direction.RIGHT) {
         direction = Direction.LEFT;
      } else if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed (KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) && direction != Direction.LEFT) {
         direction = Direction.RIGHT;
      }
   }
   
   // Method updates game elements
   private static void updateSnake () {
      // Move snake's body
      for (int i = snakeLength - 1; i > 0; i--) {
         // Block updates to next block's last position
         snakeX[i] = snakeX[i - 1];
         snakeY[i] = snakeY[i - 1];
      }

      // Move snake's head
      if (direction == Direction.UP) {
         snakeY[0]++;
      } else if (direction == Direction.DOWN) {
         snakeY[0]--;
      } else if (direction == Direction.LEFT) {
         snakeX[0]--;
      } else if (direction == Direction.RIGHT) {
         snakeX[0]++;
      }  
      
      // Check for collisions
      checkCollisions();
      
      // Check if food is eaten
      if (snakeX[0] == foodX && snakeY[0] == foodY) {
         snakeLength++;
         score++;
         spawnFood();
      }
   }
   
   private static void checkCollisions () {
      // Check if snake collides with walls
      if (snakeX[0] < 0 || snakeX[0] >= WIDTH || snakeY[0] < 0 || snakeY[0] >= HEIGHT) {
         gameOver = true;
      }
      
      // Check if snake collides with itself
      for (int i = 1; i < snakeLength; i++) {
         if (snakeX[0] == snakeX[i] || snakeY[0] == snakeY[i]) {
            gameOver = true;
         }
      }
   }
   
   private static void spawnFood () {
      foodX = random.nextInt (WIDTH / UNIT_SIZE);
      foodY = random.nextInt (HEIGHT / UNIT_SIZE);
   }
   
   private static void draw () {
      StdDraw.clear();
      
      // Draw snake
      StdDraw.setPenColor (Color.GREEN);
      for (int i = 0; i < snakeLength; i++) {
         StdDraw.filledSquare (snakeX[i] * UNIT_SIZE + UNIT_SIZE / 2.0,
               snakeY[i] * UNIT_SIZE + UNIT_SIZE / 2.0, UNIT_SIZE / 2.0);
      }      
      
      // Draw food
      StdDraw.setPenColor (Color.RED); 
      StdDraw.filledSquare (foodX * UNIT_SIZE + UNIT_SIZE / 2.0,
            foodY * UNIT_SIZE + UNIT_SIZE / 2.0, UNIT_SIZE / 2.0);      
      
      // Display score
      StdDraw.setPenColor (Color.WHITE);
      StdDraw.setFont (new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 20));
      StdDraw.text (700, 780, "Score: " + score);      
   }
   
   // Game over display
   private static void gameOverDisplay () {
      StdDraw.clear();

      StdDraw.setPenColor (Color.BLACK);
      StdDraw.setFont (new Font ("Arial", Font.BOLD, 40));
      StdDraw.text (400, 400, "Game Over!");
      StdDraw.text (400, 350, "Score: " + score);
      StdDraw.setFont(new Font ("Arial", Font.PLAIN, 20));
      StdDraw.text (400, 300, "Press Enter to Play Again");
      
      StdDraw.show();
      StdDraw.pause (100);
      
      if (StdDraw.isKeyPressed (KeyEvent.VK_ENTER)) {
         StdDraw.clear();
         launchGame();
      }
   }
}
```

This is what I have so far. It's a work in progress but I want to start with actually getting my snake moving. Thank you

Comment: Add `System.out.println (` code at various key locations in your code. Have those line output where in the program they are along with values of variables that are key at those points. And / or use a debugger: Set breakpoints, and run the code (debugging mode). When the run hits a break point, check the values of variables. Run the code one-step-at-a-time while monitoring the values of variables and noting where the code goes.